# duplicating rows with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to build a table with one row for each semimonthly pay period and semimonthly payroll amount for several hundred employees each on multiple projects. The row data format I receive from the ERP system is as follows:

> Name,Project, encumbered amount(total payroll for all periods), calcbegin(date), calend(date)

I would like to build a table which would duplicate each row n times (n is the number of semimonthly payperiods between calcbegin and calcend).

My problems are how to generate the semi monthly dates between the ranges and then produce a row with each date and associated information using mssql 2008.

Here is a sample of data. I think the CTE is the way to go but i am not sure how to make it work. I can fidgit with the dates if I can get the CTE working.

```
Existing Data                   
Name    Amount   Per amt    calcbegin   calcend Pay Periods
Name1   5000     2,500  4/15/2013   5/15/2013   2
Name2   10000    2,000  4/15/2013   6/30/2013   5

Results Requested                   
Name    Amount   Pay amt    calcbegin   calcend Payperiods
1-Name1 5000     2,500  04/15/13    4/30/2013   1
2-Name1 5000     2,500  05/01/13    5/15/2013   1

1-Name2 10000    2,000  04/15/13    4/30/2013   1
2-Name2 10000    2,000  05/01/13    5/15/2013   1
3-Name2 10000    2,000  05/16/13    5/31/2013   1
4-Name2 10000    2,000  06/01/13    6/15/2013   1
5-Name2 10000    2,000  06/16/13    6/30/2013   1
```

Comment: A database table with the date as the primary key would come in handy here.  In addition to pay periods, you could store fiscal information, holidays, and other fields you deem relevant.

Comment: Sample data and desired output would be helpful.  Not completely sure I understand your question.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a sort of date dimension. Have a look at this link  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174832.aspx, it recommends you use the `Dimension Wizard` which is part of SQL Server Data Tools.

Comment: Agreed with @sgeddes. If you provide a few example values for calcbegin and calcend, and what rows you want as a result in each case, there might be some chance that folks will understand your question. Word problems and stories are fun but solutions require real data.

Comment: It sounds like you need a CTE to generate a table with the appropriate dates.  The date calculations may get rather fiddly depending on how you figure pay dates around weekends, whether the `calcbegin` and `calend` dates always fall on pay dates, ... .  (A join on a numbers table could be used instead of a CTE.)

Answer (score 0):

With many thanks to Justin Stolle, SQL: Turn a Date Range into a List of Dates found with Google. Expanding his example I was able to build a functioning recursive CTE. Now to tweak the dates

```
WITH cte (id, b, a_p, n,e ,pp, a, ae) AS 
          (SELECT        Range_ID as id
                        ,DATEADD(wk, 2,[calc begin]) AS B
                        ,[Activity/Project] AS a_p 
                        ,Name as n
                        ,[Calc End] as E
                        ,DATEDIFF(w,[calc begin],[Calc End])/14 as pp
                        ,([Salary Encumbrance] + [Benefits Encumbrance])/(DATEDIFF(w,[calc begin],[Calc End])/14) as a
                        ,[Account Executive] as ae
               FROM EncumReport
           WHERE [Account Executive] like '%25%' 

           UNION ALL
           SELECT    Range_Id as id
                    ,(DATEADD(wk, 2, cte.b)) AS b
                    ,[activity/project] as a_p 
                    ,Name as n
                    ,[Calc End] as E
                    ,DATEDIFF(w,[calc begin],[Calc End])/14 as pp
                    ,([Salary Encumbrance] + [Benefits Encumbrance])/(DATEDIFF(w,[calc begin],[Calc End])/14) as a
                    ,[Account Executive] as ae
               FROM cte
               INNER JOIN encumreport
                      ON cte.id = range_id
                WHERE cte.b < [calc end]-7)

     SELECT id AS range_id  
           ,b AS date_within_range,a_p as Projects,  n as Name,e as EndDate, pp as PayPeriods, a as Amounts,ae as AccountExecutive  
      FROM cte
     ORDER BY id, b
```